# Can't make argument type match for APIs pointPolygonTest and flofloodFill in Opencv (Android )

Tags: android, opencv

I make sure the argument types are matched to API's requirement for `pointPolygonTest` and `flofloodFill` in `Opencv (Android )`. But I still have error of Argument type doesn't match.
The errors are

(1) The method `pointPolygonTest(MatOfPoint2f, Point, boolean)` in the type Imgproc is not applicable for the arguments `(MatOfPoint2f, Point, boolean)`.

(2) The method `floodFill(Mat, Mat, Point, Scalar)` in the type Imgproc is not applicable for the arguments `(Mat, Mat, Point, Scalar)`.
My program is

```
    public void Blob_alanysis(Mat roi_gray){
        Size s =  roi_gray.size();
        Mat mask = Mat.ones(roi_gray.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
        Mat process = roi_gray.clone();
        roi_gray = Mat.zeros(roi_gray.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1); 
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        final int gap = 5;
        Imgproc.findContours(process, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
            //search in 1st border
            boolean touching = false;
            MatOfPoint2f  ctr2f = new MatOfPoint2f( contours.get(idx) );
            for (int b = 0; b < s.height; b++) {

                if(Imgproc.pointPolygonTest(ctr2f, new Point(0,1), true) > 0)
                    touching = true;
            }
            if(touching == false){
                Mat contour = contours.get(idx);
                Imgproc.floodFill(contour, mask, new Point(0,0), new Scalar(255, 255, 255));
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
MatOfPoint contour = contours.get(idx);
MatOfPoint2f  ctr2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
contour.converTo(ctr2f, CvType.CV_32F); // or CvType.CV_32FC2
```